# To investigate SQL Server errors like timeout that happened in past

Tags: sql-server

Like IIS dumps can be used to analyze the problems, is there any way to investigate the past day/week logs on SQL Server why timeout errors had happened?

Comment: You cant.Time out errors generally can happen due to many reasons.

Comment: Look into dynamic views for detecting long-running statements, trace current activity with `profiler`.